# Why does the same commit look different in TFS and SourceTree?

Tags: git, tfs, atlassian-sourcetree

Background: We use Git for source control (part of the new Visual Studio 2013 TFS system), along with SourceTree to manage branches etc...

Reviewing a commit made by one of our developers, it shows 1 single line change in SourceTree. Checking the same commit in TFS web, it shows completely different changes. I have checked the commit ID, and they are the same so why the difference?

I am asking this question as we have introduced bugs which we didn't detect via SourceTree. Granted these changes occurred during a merge process with conflicts, but I'd expect the commit to be the same no matter where it is viewed from.

Comment: Was this a merge commit? If so, did it compare against the same parent in both tools?

Comment: What are the differences ? Line endings ?

Comment: Yes it was a merge commit... and the parents are the same. I can only assume there was a rebase done at some point - but finding the offending commit has proved fruitless.

Comment: The commit log history is completely different. This is what I don't understand. This is what scares me about using Git.